# How to "ajaxify" Faceted Search module in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: ajax, smarty, prestashop-1.7, faceted-search

I'm using Prestashop v1.7 with Mimosa Prestashop 1.7 Theme and Faceted Search module for filtering my products. My theme uses function called 'active filters' which is basically showing the list of currently active filters. This function is written within smarty .tpl code, so it's server-side code.

My question is, how can "ajaxify" this code in the simpliest way?
By "ajaxify" i mean to put the whole functionality of the server-side code in javascript code so it's output will refresh every time active filters change.

Best regards, Marek P.